# Setup VPN in Windows to allow access to specific port

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I have a VPN setup and it is working well. The server it is hosted on is not a DC. However, I need to allow a specific port (9443) on the VPN, and close it off when not on the VPN.

I have an ipad connecting to a webservice on the server; I want it to only access the webservices when on the VPN.

At the moment it can access the webservice on and off the vpn.

If I set the windows firewall to block 9443, it does not work on/off VPN

If I set firewall to allow 9443 on Private, it works both on/off

I have set local policy, Network List Manager Policies: Network : Private

RAS Interface Properties : Public

Unidentified : Public after a restart, I set the Firewall to allow 9443 on Public only.

I have tried Secured Only, set specific users, the VPN IP range, none of this works.

It cannot be that hard to allow a specific port on VPN only. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? 
cheers Pete

Comment: Most VPN's operate at OSI Layer 2 (Link Layer) or 3 (Internet Layer), but ports like specific TCP & UDP ports are part of OSI Layer 4 (Transport Layer)... Basically I am saying, depending on your VPN implementation, this likely isn't possible in a client based VPN. It may be possible in an enterprise grade router that is doing Site to Site VPN and can do packet inspection for routing rules. If you can tell us what VPN you are using, it may help... Most of my experience in client based VPNs is with OpenVPN, Windows native, or equipment specific clients, which is generally not possible.

Comment: @acejevelin - In the Linux world (and I see no reason it would not be true in Windows but could be wrong), ports are generally bound to an Interface (or all interfaces), and a firewall acts on interface+port, so it should be doable, particularly with OpenVPN which creates a tun device.

Comment: @PeteFinch what web server are you using?  Are you able to configure it to only listen on a tun/tap Interface?

Comment: Hi there, I'm using "Routing and Remote Access" on Server 2012 R2 for VPN. I'm using IIS on same server for webservices, and the port binding 9443 is set there. My understanding of VPN was that once connected you are inside the server/LAN, so the firewall should not matter. With that in mind, I have removed the rule looking at 9443, and it still fails when on VPN. I thinking it could be a routing issue? VPN assigns a 10.0.0.0/24 range, and I have yet to setup any routes from this to the server host IP range...